# Benefits of Composer if already using a PHP framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, symfony, composer-php

Dropbox's PHP SDK heavy-handedly suggests that one should use Composer to install and load their SDK. Also, version 2 of AWS's PHP SDK also offers Composer as a installation/loader (fortunately without the bias).

I'm using the Codeigniter (CI) framework which has several simple mechanisms to load modules. It has 1) a built in "vendor" folder (called "third_party" by CI, "vendor" by Composer). 2) "helper" and "library" folders to control modules I've created, e.g., `$this->load->library("blah_blah");` 3) Lastly, nothing prevents me from writing vanilla PHP `include/require "blah/blah.php";` statements for edge cases.

I don't know other PHP frameworks well, but I'd assume they handle dependencies in similarly simple manners as this would seem one of the main purposes of using a framework.

In light of all this, are their **additional** benefits to Composer beyond what the frameworks provide? Or to **replace** the parts of my code that talk to my framework with that that would work instead with Composer? In general, am I not understanding something about Composer?

Answer (score 1):

First of all read http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

> The problem that Composer solves is this:
>
> a) You have a project that depends on a number of libraries.
>
> b) Some of those libraries depend on other libraries.
>
> c) You declare the things you depend on.
>
> d) Composer finds out which versions of which packages need to be
>   installed, and installs them (meaning it downloads them into your
>   project).

You can install, update and manage dependencies of your project. Another one usefull feature that you got `autoload.php` file that load all libraries. You never need to include files anymore(with any framework that supports PSR-0 namespacing).

Here is an [article](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter) that explains how to use the composer with CI. I am sure that you can find many articles, because it is really convenient ti use a composer.

Comment: Updating packages, and doing it smartly based on other packages, appears to be a clear benefit. Autoloading is not unique because CI does that. Can Composer load dependencies in a more selective/user-defined manner than autoloading? Most of my vendor packages are used in very limited context so autoloading seems unnecessary.

Comment: @tim *Especially* if you don't need the package all the time is autoloading useful! It only loads the class *when needed* just in time.

Comment: Ah I see, but what about the large memory consumption that people report for Composer?

Comment: Its all gone with APC cache enabled

Comment: The memory consumption is reported when Composer is run on the command line to collect the dependencies. This usually happens only once in a while, and manually on your development machine - not regularly on the live production server.

Comment: @deceze just so I understand Composer's autoload.php, does it look at the name of any newly instantiated class and if that name matches a class in the vendor folder then it loads the appropriate library?

Comment: @tim Read up on PHP's autoloading mechanism, it's not a Composer invention. When you are trying to use a class that is not loaded (does not exist), PHP invokes the registered autoloader(s), giving it the name of the missing class. The autoloader can then do whatever it wants to simply include the right file in which the class is defined. It's just-in-time file inclusion, nothing more, nothing less.