# Install via Composer or copy vendor folder

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm wondering, when deploying composer-based projects why most people advice to SSH into the server and install composer and download the dependancies as following:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
composer install
```

I don't see the difference from just copying the /vendor folder when you deploy.
Do I miss anything?

**Using GIT**

When using GIT I can imagine that the /vendor folder is large and should be avoided. Is this the main reason?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906379/benefits-of-composer-if-already-using-a-php-framework

Comment: I know the benefist of composer, I'm more talking about if you deploy your project to the live server, if you FTP the /vendor folder all dependancies are also going to be transferred, So I wonder why some people prefer SSH and composer update on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `composer install` will install the dev dependencies, which is not something you want on your server. Because of that, you use `composer install --no-dev` on your server.

  This will reduce the amount of files on the server.
- Some packages might use scripts which set an absolute path somewhere, this can break up badly when not changing.
- Packages are quite large to ship using FTP

Comment: Aha didn't know about the absolute paths.. It just seems that SSH deployment is much harder then FTP deployment.. I'll have to dig into it. Thank you!

Comment: @Notflip Just tested it with a [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/) project: Doing a default `install` the vendor dir is about 480 MByte, with `install --prefer-dist` it is just about 93 MByte and with `install --prefer-dist --no-dev` it is about 86 MByte.