# Are installed Composer modules OS independent?

Tags: php, composer-php, devops

I know the scenario below is far from modern best practices but let's give it a go.

Let's assume that:

1. you have development environment and server with the same PHP version but different OSes.
2. you want/must deploy your vendors folder to the server as is.

How probable is it that: some packages will fail to work because of OS switching AND the failure could be avoided if they were installed from composer json file on the server (i.e. they're not completely platform dependent)?

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958461/install-via-composer-or-copy-vendor-folder) that absolute paths set during installation may be a problem. Are there there other possible issues?

Comment: Empiric evidence: probability is 100%. You said in the question to let's just give it a go, which is fair. But nowadays there is absolutely no reason anymore to have problems like these, as vagrant and docker are widely available and easy enough to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is pretty high because composer will work differently depending on the environment settings.

The simple example of this would be https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

which can run custom logic dependent on the installed components and prepare something only if the host OS has something available - which - has nothing to do with composer.lock

The core problem is that you want to reuse vendor folder. Composer is not made to work this way and this is why `vendor` is often mentioned in .gitignore file.
composer will behave differently per environment and its result should not be copied over.
If you want to make behaviour consistent between OS-es, use Docker or vagrant to stabilize the application and its environment.

Comment: Note that there are some valid reason to actually copy the vendor folder: https://www.codeenigma.com/build/blog/do-you-really-need-composer-production . I've always done this as it allows me to be in complete control of my dependencies.

Comment: @Loek These are not valid reasons, it is mostly looking for justification for their own laziness and inability to use `git diff` on separate dependencies. :)

Comment: @janmyszkier Any example when "*composer will work differently depending on the environment settings*"?  The point of `composer.lock` is to create predictable results of `composer install` regardless of environment.

Comment: Meh, I don't really agree. But I get the point, was just pointing out that there is no such thing as "the perfect workflow with Composer"

Comment: @Loek Maybe not, but versioning `vendor` directory is as far as possible from perfect workflow. How do you want to distinguish between dev environments (with tons of dev dependencies) and production? How do you want to browse diffs between milestones (where 90% of changes are from vendors)? Not mentioning fighting with resolving conflicts in `vendor` directory. :D You really need to do something wrong if you think that versioning `vendor` will simplify your workflow.

Comment: @rob006 - updated my answer with scripts doc, those should be run by the developer as composer install / composer update and NOT rely on vendor contents.

Answer (score 0):

They should be independent from OS, as long you commit `composer.lock` into your project. The point of `composer.lock` is to install the same packages by `composer install` independent from OS, and Composer itself does not use any absolute paths (by default). In fact Composer maintainers [discourage using it in production](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4297#issuecomment-124967050) and many issues have been closed with "Composer is not a deployment tool" as a reason. So by design you should be able to move installations between environments and on every system you will get the same packages installed by `composer install`.

The only problems may come from [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) and/or [plugins](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md), which may do some things that are not portable and you need to run it on target installation.

---

So in short: Yes, installations are independent from OS (unless you do something, that will change that).

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: by 'installations' you mean installing separately in each environment, not moving the installed packages from one place to another. So in short: 'already installed packages CAN (and probably WILL be) environment dependent (ie. can fail after transfer)'.

Comment: No, exactly opposite - already installed packages most likely will NOT be environment dependent and you should be able to move `vendor `directory between different environments without any trouble. By "installations" i mean complete application (application code + all dependencies in `vendor` directory installed by `composer install`) - you should be able to deploy such package to any environment (as long it meet requirement - PHP version and installed extensions) without the need of running composer on it.